# creating directory and uploading images to remote web server

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, nginx, web-development-server

I'm working on a website that deals with a lot of images. Users will have the ability to upload images. Images would be hosted on a separate remote Nginx server. What is the best way to create directories and upload images to the remote server? Would SSH be a viable option? anything better?

The web application is created with Spring Boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH won't really do anything to help you share or sync files across a network.

Based on your tag (linux) I suspect you could install the `nfs-kernel-server` on your "remote" server.  Network FileSystem (NFS) allows you to share directories from one OS to another across a network.  This will allow you to share a directory from your remote server with your Spring Boot server.

You can follow [these instructions](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nfs-volume-release/blob/master/jobs/nfstestserver/templates/install.erb) to set up your NFS server.

You can then mount that remote directory on your Spring Boot server with:

```
$ NFS_SERVER="<your remote server>:/<your exported directory>"
$ sudo mount -t nfs "${NFS_SERVER}" /mnt
```

Reading and writing files to /mnt will actually be reading and writing them to the directory on your remote server.  So, all you need to do then is make your Spring Boot app read and write to `/mnt`.

You could also look at the community project [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  This project is an abstraction over Storage and provides implementations for a range of Storage types including the good old Filesystem so it is ideal for your use case and will simplify your Spring application code by removing the need to code file handling controllers and services yourself.

Adding it would look something like this:

> pom.xml (assuming maven).

```
    <!-- Java API -->
    <!-- just change this depdendency if you want to store somewhere else -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- REST API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class StoreConfig {

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() throws IOException {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(new File("/mnt").getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> FileStore.java

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="files")
  public interface FileStore extends Store<String> {
  }
```

And that's it.  The `FileStore` is essentially a generic Spring ResourceLoader.  The `spring-content-fs-boot-starter` dependency will cause Spring Content to inject a filesystem-based implementation of the `FileStore` interface so you don't need to worry about implementing it yourself.  Moreover, the `spring-content-rest-boot-starter` dependency will make Spring Content also inject an implementation of an `@Controller` that forwards HTTP requests onto the methods of the `FileStore`.

All up, you will now have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based file service at `/files` that will use your `FileStore` to retrieve (and store) files in `/mnt`; i.e. on your remote NFS server.

So:

`curl -F file=@/path/to/local/an-image.jpg /files/some-directory/an-image.jpg`

will upload `an-image.jpg` and store it in `/mnt/` on your server.

`GET /files/some-directory/an-image.jpg`

will download `an-image.jpg` again.

HTH

The injected controller also supports video streaming too, in case that is useful.

If you wish to record additional metadata about the files your users upload then you can also associate content with Spring Data entities (that can be used to record this additional metadata).  You can read more about that [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/spring-content-rest-docs/).

HTH

Comment: With this setup, would it be possible to delete the files on the client "/mnt" and keep them on the remote server that is used for serving images?

Comment: @Arya, depends what you mean.  The remote directory is mounted over the top of the local directory.  When your application writes files to "/mnt" it is really writing them to the remote server and therefore they are never really *on* the local server.  Is that the behavior you mean?

Comment: yes, that's the behavior that I want. I didn't want the files stored on both servers

Comment: I setup the NFS and it works flawlessly. But I'm getting exceptions after trying to implement Spring Content. I'm getting this message https://pastebin.com/MsJQ8Cnf I also added the `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` dependency, but I'm still getting the exception message. Have you run into this before?

Comment: No I havent seen that before.  Spring Content controllers can work with, or without Spring Data REST so some of the Spring Data Rest dependencies are optional.  Spring-hateoas is either brought in by SDR, or you have to add it yourself so that JAR should be all you need.  There is an example here in case that helps: https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples/blob/master/spring-eg-content-fs-rest/pom.xml.   But feel free to raise an issue in Github and we can discuss it there if you would like.